# Как добавить поле множественного выбора (как ModelListType) в entity форме Sonata?

Tags: php, list, form, symfony, sonata

Делаю entity, столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу реализовать **поле множественного выбора** в форме Сонаты.
Нужно что-то типа **ModelListType**, только **ModelListType** позволяет выбрать **только одно** поле из списка.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что нужно реализовать множественное добавление категорий, как у новостей в сонате. Только нужно сделать возможность множественного выбора категорий. Связь ManyToMany уже прописал, коллекцию тоже. А как сам список с множественным выбором в админке в форму вывести???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен тип  поля sonata_type_collection

https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection

Также можно поиграться с четверытм параметром, из доки:

```
array(
         'edit' => 'inline',
         'inline' => 'table',
         'sortable' => 'position',
       ))
```

От него зависит отображение.

Comment: Спасибо, но это устаревший метод? для 4+ версии подходит это: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-form-type-collectiontype правильно?

Comment: @Gjnext попробуйте, я видимо на устаревшей сижу)